# WPF DataTemplate and usercontrol lifetime

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a tab control with a few tabs.  When a tab is selected, I set the content of the tab to its corresponding view model.

I also have a DataTemplate defined for the base view model that all of the other view models derive from:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BaseViewModel}">
        <view:BaseView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This way, my view models, which are nearly identical, will be displayed using the same base view.

BaseView is a user control.  In BaseView I have an Infragistics XamDataGrid defined.  It seems that only one instance of this grid is created for all of the view models, meaning I can switch between tabs as many times as I want but the user control is never recreated from scratch.

How does WPF handle the lifetime of user controls when combined with DataTemplates?

The problem I am trying to solve is that in the xaml of BaseView, I have defined a Field in the XamDataGrid like so:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
  <igDP:FieldLayout>
    <igDP:FieldLayout.FieldSettings>
      <igDP:FieldSettings DataValueChangedNotificationsActive="true" 
              AllowCellVirtualization="False"
                          AllowResize="True"
                          AllowRecordFiltering="True"/>
      </igDP:FieldLayout.FieldSettings>
      <igDP:Field Name="IsDirty" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
  </igDP:FieldLayout>
</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```

The IsDirty column (all of the view models have an IsDirty property) is only correctly collapsed the first time the grid is displayed.  When I click another tab, the grid's data source changes, a new FieldLayout is created by the grid, and it doesn't pick up the Collapsed setting for IsDirty.  As a result the IsDirty column is visible.  My thinking was if I can force the user control to be totally recreated, I could avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `DataTemplate` to Resources and set `x:Shared="false"`